# OST from Tokyo Ghoul:re episode 2 minute 00:00

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the song title from *Tokyo Ghoul:re* episode 2 at 00:00?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's Deep Dive by Yukata Yamada. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrwGXNYIDKs&index=6&list=PLB6qn5wggeAoOI4hpDoRAvN2DwfL-kEjV) is a YouTube link.